# Список клиентов с датой их самого первого заказа выдаёт InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, коллекции

Есть классы моделей

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо получить список клиентов с датой их первого заказа(заказ с самой ранней датой для каждого клиента)

Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
    var customers = dataSource.Customers.Select(c => c.Orders.Min(o => o.OrderDate));
```

Во время исполнения получаю исключение`System.InvalidOperationException: Последовательность не содержит элементов`

Объясните пожалуйста в чем ошибка и как сделать корректный запрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно заметили в соседнем ответе — эта ошибка возникает когда у клиента нет заказов.

Решение зависит от того, что вы хотите получить, если у клиента нет заказов. Возвращать `default(DateTime)`, скорее всего, в этом случае плохое решение.

Если вам не нужны те клиенты, которые не делали заказов, то их нужно предварительно отсеять:

```
// Странный запрос — он же возвращает коллекцию DateTime, а не Customer?
var customers = dataSource.Customers
                          .Where(c => c.Orders.Any())
                          .Select(c => c.Orders.Min(o => o.OrderDate));
```

Либо, если вам нужны и те клиенты, которые не делали заказов, возможно, лучше будет возвращать для них вместо даты `null`:

```
var customers = dataSource.Customers
                          .Select(c => c.Orders.Min(o => (DateTime?)o.OrderDate));
// Да, для Nullable-типов Min не падает на пустой коллекции, а возвращает null:
// https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1679
```

Ну и, в конце концов, выбрать минимальный элемент из коллекции дешевле, чем полностью ее отсортировать, не стоит забывать об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что если у клиента заказов нет, то и минимального заказа нет, потому Min падает. 
Попробуйте

```
var customers = dataSource
                      .Customers
                      .Select(c => c.Orders.Select(o=>o.OrderDate)
                                .OrderBy(date => date)
                                .FirstOrDeafult());
```

В таком виде если заказа нет, то вернется значение по умолчанию для даты.

Comment: хм, а хорошо ли возвращать `default(DateTime)`, если нет заказов? Нужно с этим быть внимательным, какой-нибудь трудноуловимый баг может вылезти...

Comment: @АндрейNOP да я просто поспешил с ответом :)